# Snapped powerlink, new powerlink or new chain?

Tags: chain

If your chain snaps at the powerlink, do you need to replace just the powerlink? Or is the entire chain comprised?

Comment: Hypothetical or actually happened? The powerlink shouldn't be any weaker than normal link and there's probably something else wrong if it breaks.

Comment: But what is wrong in that case? The chain is only a month old. Becomes an expensive joke if stuff just falls apart for no reason

Comment: Usually if you break at the powerlink, its because you didn't install the powerlink properly. PUt on a new powerlink and see what happens.

Comment: Do you know how worn your chain is?  If its almost done then a new chain might be advisable.  Otherwise just replace the joiner-link, and add a second to your on-bike spares bag.

Answer (score 4):

Depends what is damaged.

Clearly the powerlink needs replacing if it broke or snapped.  They tend not to just "come apart" under load but theres a small chance it never closed right.

Look at the end links in the chain, that would connect to the power link.  If there is excess play in those end pins then it may be time to replace the chain.

If the chain is worn and you can feel play in all the links, then just replace it.  Chains are consumables.

But if the chain seems okay then just replace the powerlink with a new one, and buy a second new spare one for your toolkit.

Comment: Yeah, my guess was installation error, but OP might also want to be aware that those links aren't meant to have unlimited uses. I think SRAM and KMC both spec their master links for 3 or 4 maximum open/close operations before they should be replaced. Dunno if that's relevant but it's something that often goes unnoticed.

Answer (score -4):

Powerlinks are a liability, best thing to do to do without it (get a regular link and replace on your chain) and then invest in a small and light chain tool (under 10 bucks but it's a tool you have it for all your life).

With a little practice you can open and close your chain as quickly as with your powerlink but you don't have to worry about that kind of problem.

Comment: Let's have a competition. You post a video where you break and join a chain without powerlink under 10 seconds, and I'll beat your time with one.

Comment: Without powerlink = no powerlink snapping = no issue with the chain, that's all

Comment: "With a little practice you can open and close your chain as quickly as with your powerlink". Quoting here before it gets edited away.

Comment: Powerlinks are fine - one-use shimano/campy pins are fine too.   The question specifically asks whether a broken powerlink means OP needs to replace the chain as well.  If you had broken a normal pin/link on your chain then it would definitely mean a new chain.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Your answer has been flagged as "Not an Answer" or is getting downvoted by the community because it either doesn't answer the question, or doesn't add valuable information to the answers that already exist. Answers like this will often be deleted or converted to comments. Please use the "edit" link to modify your answer to more clearly address the original question, or the "delete" link to remove it.